# C++ function declaration error; undeclared identifier

Tags: xcode, function, xcode6

background:
working through Bjarne Stroustrup, Programming Principles and Practice Using C++, 2nd Edition. I am at try this 4.6.4. I have been stuck on this for a various aspects e.g. sort and vector did not work like in the txt book:

```
sort()
vector<string> bad_word_list =  {"buck", "Buck", "idiot"};
```

my system: 
xcode 6.3.2
C++ standard Library - libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++ 11 support)

```
  #include "std_lib_facilities.h"
 int main()
{
vector<string> words;
for (string temp; cin>>temp;) {
    words.push_back(temp);
    cout << "Number of words: "<<words.size()<<'\n';
 }
sort(words.begin(), words.end());

for (int i=0; i<words.size(); ++i) {
    int bad_word;
    bad_word = check_word(words[i]); // <----
    if (bad_word == 1) {
        cout << "BEEP";
    } else
        cout << words[i] << '\n';
}


return 0;
 }
```

---

```
int check_word(string x)
{
vector<string> bad_word_list;
bad_word_list.push_back("duck");
for (int i=0; i<bad_word_list.size(); ++i) {
    if (x == bad_word_list[i]) {
        return 1;
    } 

}
return 0;
}
```

The current problem is check_word comes up as undeclared identifier. This still happens when i remove all the code inside main and directly call check_word.

note: when i type in check_word the auto prompt/filler detects the function.

Comment: it is now, and it worked. It`s the simple stuff that is really slowing me down (like this).  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare check_word before you use it.